# How to change file system encoding via python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, filesystems

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'UTF-8'
```

How do I change that? I know how to change the default system encoding.

```
>>> reload(sys)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding('ascii')
```

But there is no `sys.setfilesystemencoding`.

Comment: Note that there was [`sys.setfilesystemencoding`](https://bugs.python.org/issue3187#msg74080) function and also env var [`PYTHONFSENCODING`](https://bugs.python.org/issue8622) in early versions of Python 3.x. They were problematic and got removed, now Python uses locale encoding as the filesystem encoding. See [_Painful History of the Filesystem Encoding_](https://vstinner.github.io/painful-history-python-filesystem-encoding.html) from Victor Stinner's blog.

Comment: Also note that per https://peps.python.org/pep-0686/ -- in the Python 3.15 timeframe we intend to make UTF-8 the default for text IO regardless of environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file system encoding is, in many cases, an inherent property of the operating system. It cannot be changed — if, for some reason, you need to create files with names encoded differently than the filesystem encoding implies, don't use Unicode strings for filenames. (Or, if you're using Python 3, use a bytes object instead of a string.)

[See the documentation for details.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) In particular, note that, on Windows systems, the file system is *natively* Unicode, so no conversion is actually taking place, and, consequently, it's impossible to use an alternative filesystem encoding.

Answer (score 15):

There are two ways to change it:

1. (linux-only) `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`
   before launching python:

```sh
$ LC_CTYPE=C python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())'
ANSI_X3.4-1968
$ LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())'
UTF-8
```

Note that LANG serves as the default value for LC_CTYPE if it is not set, while LC_ALL overrides both LC_CTYPE and LANG)

2. monkeypatching:

```sh
import sys
sys.getfilesystemencoding = lambda: 'UTF-8'
```

Both methods let functions like `os.stat` accept unicode (python2.x) strings.
Otherwise those functions raise an exception when they see non-ascii symbols in the filename.

**Update:**
In the (1) variant the locale has to be available (present in `locale -a`) for this setting to have the desired effect.

Comment: @sureshvv What is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. Had to add LANG=en_US.UTF8 to  /etc/environment and reboot.

Comment: @sureshvv reboot is definitely an overkill in this situation, but I'm glad that you've resolved the issue anyway. Did you launch python directly from command line or as a system service?

Comment: Only from the command line. The change I made did not become effective until reboot.

Comment: @sureshvv It's not surprising about `/etc/environment` but `export LANG=en_US.UTF8` has immediate effect

Comment: Would setting LC_ALL interfere with LANG? To be safe, I set both. May be they cancelled out.

Comment: @sureshvv The specific env var that is responsible for `getfilesystemencoding` is LC_CTYPE. If it is not set, LANG is used as the default. Finally, if LC_ALL is set, it overrides both LC_CTYPE and LANG.

Comment: @sureshvv See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522990/where-py-filesystemdefaultencoding-is-set-in-python-source-code)

Comment: @wim UTF8 and UTF-8 are synonyms. Internally it will be UTF-8 anyway. en_US and C have subtle differences. For example, LC_ALL=C results in DD/MM/YYYY date format and en_US gives MM/DD/YYYY. Both C.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8 will set `getfilesystemencoding()` correctly. Nowadays it is utf-8 out of the box (debian and ubuntu). Are you dealing with an old pc?

Comment: @wim fixed now.

Comment: Something else that might be worth mentioning: the locale has to be available (present in `locale -a`) for this setting to have the desired effect. If the necessary langpack are not installed, then even when you've set `LC_CTYPE=C.utf-8` you can still have `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returning ascii.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins I think you should remove method 2 from the answer. _It does not work_. Python uses the locale encoding as the filesystem encoding, and monkeypatching this function after the interpreter has already started will not change anything that matters. I don't believe this would have worked even back in python 2.7 either, tbh - `os.stat` does not call `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`.

Comment: @wim It worked at the moment of writing. This whole story was a nasty bug in python implementation. Believe it or not, back in the 2015 python was unable to open files with non-ascii chars in filename ootb. Thankfully it is fixed now. Why are you investigating an issue from the all-forgotten past? Do you have a valid use case for it in 2022? Btw you have a broken link in your profile.

Comment: Yes, I saw a case recently where Python 3.6 was still using ANSI_X3.4-1968  even though the var was set to C.UTF-8. It turned out to be because the docker image in use did not have any langpacks installed (presumably to save space and slim down containers). Which broken link in profile? I checked and did not see one..

Comment: @wim Yes, working with slim docker images is like walking on thin ice :) https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/wimglenn.com?proto=http&www=1

Comment: @wim I vaguely remember that one of the encoding-related workarounds only worked if run in `sitecustomize.py`. I tried to reproduce this bug on a number of machines, but couldn't fine one with ANSI_X3.4-1968 encoding.