# where Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding is set in python source code

Tags: python, python-2.7, locale

i am curious about how python source code set the value of Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding. And i have receive a strange thing.

Since python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) about sys.getfilesystemencoding() said that:

> On Unix, the encoding is the user’s preference according to the result of nl_langinfo(CODESET), or None if the nl_langinfo(CODESET) failed.

i use python 2.7.6

```

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.getfilesystemencoding()
>>>'UTF-8'
>>>import locale
>>>locale.nl_langinfo(locale.CODESET)
>>>'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

```
Here is the question: why the value of getfilesystemencoding() is different from the value of locale.nl_landinfo() since the doc says that getfilesystemencoding() is derived from locale.nl_landinfo().

Here is the locale command output in my terminal:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary: `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` behaves as documented. The confusion is due to the difference between `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` (user's preference) and the default C locale.

---

The script always starts with the default C locale:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.nl_langinfo(locale.CODESET)
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

But `getfilesystemencoding()` uses user's locale:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'UTF-8'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, '')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.nl_langinfo(locale.CODESET)
'UTF-8'
```

Empty string as a locale name [selects a locale based on the user choice of the appropriate environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html).

```
$ LC_CTYPE=C python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())'
ANSI_X3.4-1968
$ LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())'
UTF-8
```

---

> where can i find the source code about setting Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding.

There are two places in the source code for Python 2.7:

- [`bltinmodule.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#l17) specifies `Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding` on Windows and OS X
- [`Py_InitializeEx()` sets it on other Unix systems](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#l283) -- notice: `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` is called before `nl_langinfo(CODESET)` and it is restored back `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, saved_locale)` after.

---

> Can you give me some advice how to search some keywords in python source code

To find these places:

- [clone Python 2.7 source code](https://docs.python.org/devguide/):

  ```
  $ hg clone https://hg.python.org/cpython && cd cpython
  $ hg update 2.7
  ```
- search for `Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding *=` regex in your editor e.g.:

  ```
  $ make TAGS # to create tags table
  ```

  in Emacs: `M-x tags-search RET Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding *= RET` and `M-,` to continue the search.

Comment: can you please tell me where can i find the source code about setting __Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding__.

Comment: @andy: I've added summary and links to the source code for Python 2.7

Comment: i see it, that's very good. Can you give me some advice how to search some keywords in python source code.

Comment: @andy: I've added one possible way to find where `Py_FileSystemDefaultEncoding` is defined