# Set filesystem encoding for python 3 on the Intel Edison

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, intel-edison

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a file `test.txt` with content `This is 中文` (i.e., UTF-8 encoded non-ASCII text).
2. Custom-compile python 3.5.2 on the Intel Edison.
3. Launch the custom-compiled python3 interpreter and issue the following piece of code:

   ```
   with open('test.txt', 'r') as fh:
       fh.readlines()
   ```

**Actual behavior:**

A `UnicodeDecodeError` exception is thrown. The file is opened as 'ASCII' instead of 'UTF-8' by default:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

On a "regular" Linux system this problem is easily solved by setting a proper locale, see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172002/how-to-change-file-system-encoding-via-python) or [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python). On the Intel Edison, however, I cannot set the `LC_CTYPE` since the default Yocto Linux distribution is missing locales (see e.g. [this page](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/wiki/Intel-Edison)).

I also tried to use a couple of other hacks like

```
import sys; sys.getfilesystemencoding = lambda: 'UTF-8'
import locale; locale.getpreferredencoding = lambda: 'utf-8'
```

And I tried setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` environment variable before starting the python interpreter.

However, none of this works. The only workaround is to specify the encoding explicitly as a command line parameter to the `open` command. This works for the above snippet, but it won't set the system-wide default for all packages I am using (that will implicitly open files as ASCII and may or may not offer me a way to override that default behavior).

What is the proper way to set the python interpreter default filesystem encoding? (Of course without installing unneeded system-wide locales.)

Comment: Why not just use `open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')`? Explicit is better than implicit. Don't use hacks.

Comment: `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is not used to determine the encoding of newly opened files. Replacing `locale.getpreferredencoding` won't work, because the *C code that opens files* won't call the Python version, it has direct access to the original C function.

Comment: `PYTHONIOENCODING` applies to `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, not to `open()`.

Comment: Why not just use `LC_ALL='.UTF-8'` when running Python? You don't need to set the whole locale, just that environment variable should suffice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I pointed out that adding the `encoding='utf8'` option works for the code snippet. But it won't work for all packages that I import and which open files internally. I need to have the behavior of having `LC_CTYPE` set to `.UTF-8` without being able to set this explicitly (as the Yocto Linux distribution does not install locales by default).

Comment: It's just an environment variable, set it only for those Python processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `LC_ALL` environment variable to alter the default:

```
$ python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())'
UTF-8
$ LC_ALL='.ASCII' python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())'
US-ASCII
```

I tested this both on OS X and CentOS 7.

As for your other attempts, here is why they don't work:

- `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` applies to filenames only (e.g. `os.listdir()` and friends).
- The `io` module doesn't actually use the  `locale.getpreferrredencoding()` function, so altering the function on the module won't have an effect. A lightweight [`_bootlocale.py` bootstrap module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/_bootlocale.py) is used instead. More on that below.
- `PYTHONIOENCODING` only applies to `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stdstderr`

If setting environment variables ultimately fails, you can still patch the `_bootlocale` module:

```
import _bootlocale

old = _bootlocale.getpreferredencoding  # so you can restore
_bootlocale.getpreferredencoding = lambda *args: 'UTF-8'
```

This works for me (again on OS X and CentOS 7, tested with 3.6):

```
>>> import _bootlocale
>>> open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w').encoding  # showing pre-patch setting
'UTF-8'
>>> old = _bootlocale.getpreferredencoding
>>> _bootlocale.getpreferredencoding = lambda *a: 'ASCII'
>>> open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w').encoding  # gimped hook
'ASCII'
```

Comment: My question is specifically about the Intel Edison. That is an embedded system with a customizable, minimal Linux system that lacks many features which macOS X and Desktop Linux distributions have. In particular, there are no locales installed so setting `LC_*` just leads to an error message: `-sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (.UTF-8): No such file or directory`

Comment: @user8472: but that's just a warning. Does *Python* work?

Comment: The output from the python interpreter is ALWAYS `ANSI_X3.4-1968`, regardless of the content of the `LC_ALL` environment variable. Likewise, the `open` command in the interpreter ALWAYS fails UNLESS I explicitly set the encoding to `'utf-8'`. The `open` commands in packages I include also fail reproducibly, regardless of the value of the `LC_ALL` environment variable.

Comment: @user8472: well, that sucks. Only goes to show that you should never, ever ever ever, rely on the locale when opening files and you **must** use `encoding='...'` whenever you want to read textual data that is not ASCII. However, I figured out what hook the `io` module *really* uses, see the update.

Comment: Yes, that works! Both for my code (for which I agree I **should** specify the encoding explicitly) and for code I import (on which I have no control and where I may not be able to specify encodings explicitly).